# Как мне определить, когда изображения закончили загрузку?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/Geallary.css';
import { IoIosAdd } from "react-icons/io";


class Geallary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      file: []

    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' id='file' onChange={this.handleChange}  ></input>
        <label for='file' id='label' ><IoIosAdd /></label>
        <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/44_20140925_1955853838.gif" className="img-thumbnail" />
        <img src="https://www.sunhome.ru/i/wallpapers/43/novogodnie-kartinki-animaciya.240x320.gif" className="img-thumbnail" />
        <img src="https://bestgif.su/_ph/56/2/598465583.gif" className="img-thumbnail" />
        <img className="img" src={this.state.file} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а каждой есть событие onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать  метод `onLoad` как и правильно отметил  *@Stranger in the Q*.

Все просто привязываете картинке функцию который будет отслеживать загрузился фото или нет.

Также советую добавить функцию ошибку `handleImageErrored` для отлавливания ошибок если вдруг не загрузитсья показать ошибку пользователю чтобы он не смотрел бесконечно в пустой блок.

В примере если у вас хороший  интернет то можно не заметить как слово `loading` меняется после загрузки картинки на `loaded`.

Рабочий [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hoover-28bnd)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: "loading" };
  }

  handleImageLoaded = () => {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "loaded" });
  }

  handleImageErrored = () => {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "failed to load" });
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: "100%"
    };
    return (
      <>
        <img
          {...{ style }}
          src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/24866.jpg"
          onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded}
          onError={this.handleImageErrored}
          alt="wallpaper"
        />
        {this.state.imageStatus}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```